# DynamoDB Batch Update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any API in DynamoDB to update a batch of items? There is an API to write new items in batches (`BatchWriteItem`) and update single item using `UpdateItem`, but is it possible to update multiple items in one call?

Answer (score 53):

There is no batch update item API available in DynamoDB at the moment.

[DynamoDB API operations list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html)

Comment: Dec 2021: 5 years later, this is still the case (excluding using transactions)

Comment: Mar 2022: still the case

Comment: There is a workaround available actually. See the answer by @sajed and a little added information by me (@ap14) in addition to that.

Comment: Dec 2023: still the case

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old question by now, but DynamoDB recently added a Transaction api which supports update:

Update — Initiates an UpdateItem operation to edit an existing item's attributes or add a new item to the table if it does not already exist. Use this action to add, delete, or update attributes on an existing item conditionally or without a condition.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

Comment: Do you know if we might be able to provide the flag UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES while calling the update or does it removes values of all attributes that are null?

Comment: This works but for whoever using this be mindful of transaction costing double the normal update.

Comment: Worth noting: Transactions don't allow for Return Values.
In my use case where what I wanted to do is increment some counters - this would require at least 2 operations transact write + transact read - which is not ideal.

Answer (score 12):

I reached this thread on similar query, hope this might help.

DynamoDB supports Batch Statement Execution which is described in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchExecuteStatement.html). This works with client object rather than resource object. Then I used the PartiQL update statement supported by DynamoDB and described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html).

Python code reference looks something like this:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

batch = ["UPDATE users SET active='N' WHERE email='<user_email>' RETURNING [ALL|MODIFIED] [NEW|OLD] *;", "UPDATE users ..."]  # Limit to 25 per batch
request_items = [{'Statement': _stat} for _stat in batch]
batch_response = client.batch_execute_statement(Statements=request_items)
```

This is minimal code. You can use multi-threading to execute multiple batches at once.

Comment: I wonder how it performs compares to doing `update_item` one by one?  2x speedup? 10x? Slower?

Comment: BatchExecuteStatement does not support upserts when doing UPDATE

Answer (score 9):

With PartiQL you can execute batch insert and update just like SQL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.multiplestatements.batching.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30197765)

Comment: BatchExecuteStatement does not support upserts when doing UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

BatchWriteItem cannot update items. To update items, use the UpdateItem action.
BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Answer (score 2):

I use `DynamoDBMapper.batchSave(Iterable<? extends Object> objectsToSave)` for this purpose.

Comment: from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#DynamoDBMapper.Methods.batchSave batchSave Saves objects to one or more tables using one or more calls to the AmazonDynamoDB.batchWriteItem method. This method does not provide transaction guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no batch update currently , you can use a single update Item call and have a workflow over it like AWS SWF or AWS step functions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Comment: There is also a batch update capability when the updates are made using PartiQL, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchExecuteStatement-property
This apparently allows up to 25 single items to be updated
Also, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html

Answer (score 0):

I use a dynamoDB update trigger, then I made a template that said to me what items I should modify, I put them on a queue and them read queue messages in other to update one by one

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a batch delete but I did this in a python lambda function just now:

```
    import json
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    idList = [
        "id1",
        "id2
        ...
        "id100",
    ]

    for itemID in idList:
        test = client.update_item(
                TableName='Your-Table-Name',
                Key={
                    'id': {
                        'S': itemID
                    }
                },
                UpdateExpression="set exressionToChange=:r",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':r': {'S':'New_Value'}},
                ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
        
    
    return
```

To get the idList, I downloaded the values in a CSV, copied them into VSCode and then did a find and replace with regex (`CMD`-`F` then click `.\*`) and set
find to "`.*`" and replace to "`$0`",
which basically replaces every line with itself in quotes and a comma

So basically before:

```
    id1
    id2
    id3
    ...
```

And after

```
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3",
    ...
```

Just replace "`idList = [...]`" with your ids, "`Your-Table-Name`", "`expressionToChange`" and lastly, "`New_Value`".

Also you will have give your lambda function permission to "Update Item" in DynamoDB or you will get an error