# How to update multiple items in a DynamoDB table at once

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm using DynamoDB and I need to update a specific attribute on multiple records. Writing my requirement in pseudo-language I would like to do an update that says "update table *persons* set relationshipStatus = 'married' where personKey IN (key1, key2, key3, ...)" (assuming that personKey is the  KEY in my DynamoDB table).

In other words, I want to do an update with an IN-clause, or I suppose one could call it a batch update. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478904/dynamodb-batch-update) link that asks explicitly if an operation like a batch update exists and the answer there is that it does not. It does not mention IN-clauses, however. The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) shows that IN-clauses are supported in ConditionalExpressions (100 values can be supplied at a time). However, I am not sure if such an IN-clause is suitable for my situation because I still need to supply a mandatory KEY attribute (which expects a single value it seems - I might be wrong) and I am worried that it will do a full table scan for each update.

So my question is: how do I achieve an update on multiple DynamoDB records at the same time? At the moment it almost looks like I will have to call an update statement for each Key one-by-one and that just feels really wrong...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As you noted, DynamoDB does not support a batch update operation. You would need to query for, and obtain the keys for all the records you want to update. Then loop through that list, updating each item one at a time.

Comment: can i use for loop and pass my primary id as key to update multiple records?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i was not sure that whether in for loop the multiple items will be updated or not. but it did work.

Comment: @prakash tank so was you able to use IN in your query or you just did multiple updates within the loop?

Comment: @Forest : i updated my values within the loop. i haven't tried IN as i  didn't find much.

Comment: Highlighting here that if your process crashes(many reasons) during the update operation(for loop) you may have unrecoverable inconsistencies in the db if you don't have any reconciliation system in place.@MarkB how do you deal with such scenarios? for example suppose a api request may lead to update of 100 items, how do you make that update possible without any chances of data being inconsistent.

Comment: @wings DynamoDB now supports transactions, which you would use if you are worried about that scenario: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

Comment: @MarkB there is a limitation of 25 items and 4MB data size in DDB write transaction that's why I specifically mentioned 100 items to be updated :)

Comment: @wings you are doing something not supported directly by DynamoDB. I guess you need to use some try/catch logic to keep a list of failed updates outside of DynamoDB. You might want to ask your AWS Account Rep for help with something like that. Your situation is specific enough that it at least warrants a separate question here on Stackoverflow instead of tacking on to this existing question.

Answer (score 17):

You can use TransactWriteItems action to update multiple records in DynamoDB table.

The official documentation available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html), also you can see TransactWriteItems javascript/nodejs example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#transactWriteItems-property).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to solve same issue and thinking about using TransactWriteItems. But I am confused. Can transact write update many records at the same time or it can do multiple actions on one record? like add, get, update etc. I could not figure than out from documentation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, TransactWriteItems is a synchronous write operation that groups up to 25 action requests.

Comment: It also uses 2x the capacity units

Comment: @KP transact write item can not perform multiple actions on the same item.

Comment: It was recently increased from 25 actions per transction to 100 actions: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-dynamodb-supports-100-actions-per-transaction/

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if it has changed since the answer was given but it's possible now

See the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

I have used it like this in javascript (mapping the new blocks to an array of objects with the wanted structure:

```
let params = {}
let tableName = 'Blocks';

params.RequestItems[tableName] = _.map(newBlocks, block => {
    return {
        PutRequest: {
            Item: {
                'org_id': orgId,
                'block_id': block.block_id,
                'block_text': block.block_text
            },
            ConditionExpression: 'org_id <> :orgId AND block_id <> :block_id',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':orgId': orgId,
                ':block_id': block.block_id
            }
        }
    }
})

docClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {
   .... and do stuff with the result
```

You can even mix `puts` and `deletes`

And if your using dynogels (you cant mix em due to dynogels support but what you can do is for updating (use create because behind the scenes it casts to the batchWrite function as put's)

```
var item1 = {email: 'foo1@example.com', name: 'Foo 1', age: 10};
var item2 = {email: 'foo2@example.com', name: 'Foo 2', age: 20};
var item3 = {email: 'foo3@example.com', name: 'Foo 3', age: 30};

Account.create([item1, item2, item3], function (err, acccounts) {
  console.log('created 3 accounts in DynamoDB', accounts);
});
```

Note this from DynamoDB limitations ([from the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)):

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.

If i remember correctly i think dynogels is chunking the requests into chucks of 25 before sending them off and then collecting them in one promise and returns *(though im not 100% certain on this)* - otherwise a wrapper function would be pretty simple to assemble

Comment: This works if you are ok blowing away the data on the put request. Batch write doesn't update items, so any objects that match an existing ID will completely replace the existing.  In the case where overwriting is not ok, the update would need to happen... probably in a loop

Comment: I'd like to clarify the above comment further. The example above is a PUTRequest. A PUT is intended to create/set the value of a particular key (POST creates the value as a child of the key). This example isn't about updating an attribute in a record/document, it's about batch PUTs for keys. That's why this "overwrites records" and doesn't "update contents of records".

For those of us coming here from a T-SQL/relational query world, PUT is more like INSERT than UPDATE because INSERT intents to affect the entire row while UPDATE is meant for changing one or more "columns" of the "row".

Comment: @rainabba so as long as your not utilising patch requests this is useful but doing full data obj posts then it should be done 1 by 1

Answer (score 9):

DynamoDb is not designed as relational DB to support the native transaction. It is better to design the schema to avoid the situation of multiple updates at the first place. Or if it is not practical in your case, please keep in mind you may improve it when restructuring the design.

The only way to update multiple items at the same time is use TransactionWrite operation provided by DynamoDB. But it comes with a limitation (25 at most for example). So keep in mind with that, you probable should do some limitation in your application as well. In spite of being very costly (because of the implementation involving some consensus algorithm), it is still mush faster than a simple loop. And it gives you ACID property, which is probably we need most. Think of a situation using loop, if one of the updates fails, how do you deal with the failure? Is it possible to rollback all changes without causing some race condition? Are the updates idempotent? It really depends on the nature of your application of cause. Be careful.

Another option is to use the thread pool to do the network I/O job, which can definitely save a lot of time, but it also has the same failure-and-rollback issue to think about.

Comment: Don't use `DynamoDB`, that is the correct answer.