# How to Partially Update a DynamoDB Table?

Tags: javascript, database, rest, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

We're having a lot of trouble doing a partial update in DynamoDB.

Trying to use best practices in NoSQL by using aggregates instead of entities so our data looks a bit like this:

```
[
{
    "userLogin": {
        "ipAddress": "123.222.121.1234",
        "lastLogin": "2017-10-16T17:38:59.818Z",
        "userAgent": "bob",
        "geoLocation": "lat-121 long-312"
    },
    "addresses": {
        "billingAddress": {
            "streetName": "york street",
            "province": "ontario",
            "city": "toronto",
            "streetNumber": "18",
            "postalCode": "m5a2v7"
        },
        "businessAddress": {
            "streetName": "york street",
            "province": "ontario",
            "city": "toronto",
            "streetNumber": "18",
            "postalCode": "m5a2v7"
        },
        "mailingAddress": {
            "streetName": "york street",
            "province": "ontario",
            "city": "toronto",
            "streetNumber": "18",
            "postalCode": "m5a2v7"
        },
    },
    "paymentTransaction": {
        "orderId": 5,
        "amount": 75,
        "transactionTimestamp": "2017-10-16T17:38:59.818Z"
    },
    "userId": "00uc4sxyi7gfQoFum0h7",
    "phoneNumbers": {
        "workNumber": "647-123-1234",
        "homeNumber": "647-321-4321"
    },
    "userProfile": {
        "role": "admin",
        "verifiedTimeStamp": "2017-10-16T17:38:59.818Z",
        "termsConditionTimeStamp": "2017-10-16T17:38:59.818Z",
        "verified": "TRUE",
        "createdTimeStamp": "2017-10-16T17:38:59.818Z",
        "termsConditionVersion": "1.0",
        "email": "kyle.truong@test.io"
    }
}
```

]

All we want to do is make a request with a body like this:

```
PUT /api/user-profiles/00uc4sxyi7gfQoFum0h7
body: {
    "userLogin": { "lastLogin": "2017-12-16T17:38:59.818Z" }
}
```

and have it update the one attribute in the User table.

The updateItem API seems to require defining the attributes you want to update before updating them, but we want it be more flexible and dynamic based on the body of the request.

This thread seems to say it's not possible:

[How to update multiple items in a DynamoDB table at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229149/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-at-once)

If so, what's the best way to go about updating just a partial attribute object within an item in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dynamoDB if your userLogin is a map type then you can update the value of lastLoginkey. In Java below code may help. Here column name would be userLogin  and newKey would be lastLogin. Full code snippet can be found [here](http://www.tryyourskill.com/aws/insert-or-append-key-values-map-in-dynamodb-using-java)

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey(primaryKey,primaryKeyValue).withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW).
        withUpdateExpression("set #columnName." + newKey + " = :columnValue").
        withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#columnName", updateColumn)).
        withValueMap(new ValueMap().with(":columnValue", newValue)).withConditionExpression("attribute_exists("+ updateColumn +")");

table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

Comment: How would you modify this if you didn't know exactly which column(s) and keys you wanted to update?

What if the request body contained a key, or multiple keys, with 'x' amount of fields?

I'm thinking of using the same format as your answer but with more conditional expressions and some kind of iterator of the request body to check for multiple keys so I could instantiate more update operations. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes you can use iteration to update multiple keys and it will work for you