# update dynamodb golang with multiple keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, dynamodb-queries

I want to update a dynamodb table with a list of keys. My struct is :

{
 ID int,
 Code String

}

I have a list of Code values, and i want the dynamodb update when the register is equal with any of Code values:

{ID : 1, Code: "anything"} {ID: 1, Code: "another_code"}

when the table find a ID with value 1 and Code like "anything", or "another_code" which update the value of the register. I did noticed that is not possible, i should use a loop and update each line per time, is true?

```
return dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    TableName:                 &tableName,
    Key:                       attributeObject,
    UpdateExpression:          &expression,
    ConditionExpression:       &conditional,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  expressionAttributeNames,        
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update multiple items in a DynamoDB table at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229149/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-at-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, DynamoDB's [Batch operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.BatchOperations) only support reading or inserting multiple items at a time; updating existing values is not yet supported. So like you suggested, you'll need to loop through each key you want to update and make a separate request.

See also: [How to update multiple items in a DynamoDB table at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229149/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-at-once)