# Updating a single column for every row in DynamoDB via Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Let say I have a table with 1000 rows and I want to update the 3rd and 4th column with a constant value for every row in Boto3 (Python):

```
table.update_item(
                    Key={
                        'id': item['id']
                    },
                    UpdateExpression='SET value1 = :val1, value2 = :val2',
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':val1': someValue1,
                        ':val2': someValue2
                    }
                )
```

I could run a loop over each row and do something like the following, but wonder if there is a more efficient full table update strategy I can run for this.

Comment: What’s the key schema of the table? From the example it looks like you only have Partition Key, is that correct?

Comment: this is just a dummy table, so only a single primary key that's a string (as an example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update multiple items in a DynamoDB table at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229149/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-at-once)