# How do you update an AWS Dynamodb with a condition and not a key

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

How do you go about updating a DynamoDB table by condition and not a key?  I want to set all **active** flags to false where **gameid** = xxxx and **age** > 30.

Comment: You must supply the key for the update to work. The condition is used to determine if the update should happen. For example if 2 processed are going to update the same record that has an version then you can set the condition to update the record only if it is that version. If you do not have a key to update with then you will probably need to scan the table OR you need to create a GSI that contains your field that you want as the index to do the update.

Comment: Ahhh so you CAN'T do bulk updates in DynamoDB and Lambda?

Comment: So I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229149/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-at-once, which states:

As you noted, DynamoDB does not support a batch update operation. You would need to query for, and obtain the keys for all the records you want to update. Then loop through that list, updating each item one at a time.  Major miss on my design.

Comment: You can use Lambda, but you will need to use a loop and read through your index and do the updates. Efectivly read once to find the record and once to write the new record. Like I say maybe look into creating a GSI (Global Secondary Index) if you can for your gameid field to be a key that you can update with. You can then do a query based on that key and loop through those specific records to update them based on the key. That way you do not do a full table scan and you only update the records that you need to update.

Answer (score 1):

When you design a DynamoDB schema you need to think differently than when you design a relational schema. Relational databases are good for small datasets, where you can simply go over all the records and update some values in them. However, it doesn't scale for millions and more records, and you need to think differently and use a NoSQL solution such as DynamoDB.

The main power of DynamoDB is the almost unlimited scale of LOOKUP operations that are mostly GET and PUT of a single or a small set of records. The solutions that were offered in the comments to the questions are good and you can:

- Query the records that need to change (using PartiQL, for example) with the condition `SELECT * FROM "Games"  WHERE gameid = "xxxx" and age > 30 and flag = "Active"`
- Loop over the records and update each with the relevant value

Nevertheless, you should consider a different design for your tables, and think about the reason for the bulk update. Maybe you should have another table where you can simply update a single record to apply the change that you want. For example, if the records are part of an object called `Round`, point the records to this object and update the state of this single round record when needed.

It is very easy to read two records (one for game and one for round) instead of only a single record of a game. Especially, if you can minimize the complexity and cost of updating many records of games with such a flag.